# Exposing normal and const iterators in STL wrapper class

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Say I have a class which is a wrapper around stl::list and I want to be able to use range looping:

```
 #include <list>
 using std::list;

 template <typename T>
 class list_wrapper
 {
 public:
      list<T> _list;

      typename list<T>::const_iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
      typename list<T>::const_iterator end() { return l.end(); } 
      typename list<T>::iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
      typename list<T>::iterator end() { return l.end(); } 
 };

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
      list_wrapper<int> myList;
      // insert any number of elements into myList._list

      /*
           i want to be able to do:

           for (auto& i : myList) { ... }

           and

           for (const auto& i : myList { ... }    
      */

      return 0;
 }
```

It seems I can use `iterator`s **or** `const_iterator`s as `begin()` and `end()` cannot be overloaded, with the error message:

```
 323070236/source.cpp:16:32: error: ‘typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator wrap_list<T>::begin()’ cannot be overloaded
 typename list<T>::iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
                            ^~~~~
 323070236/source.cpp:14:38: error: with ‘typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::const_iterator wrap_list<T>::begin()’
 typename list<T>::const_iterator begin() { return l.begin(); }
                                  ^~~~~
 323070236/source.cpp:17:32: error: ‘typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator wrap_list<T>::end()’ cannot be overloaded
 typename list<T>::iterator end() { return l.end(); }
                            ^~~
 323070236/source.cpp:15:38: error: with ‘typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::const_iterator wrap_list<T>::end()’
 typename list<T>::const_iterator end() { return l.end(); }
```

How would I be able to use both `::iterator` and `::const_iterator` here?

Comment: `typename list<T>::const_iterator begin() const`  (`const` added)?

Comment: you need to have `const` function.  working [here](https://onlinegdb.com/hmXeh5Okq)

Comment: they can be overloaded, but the two overloads must differ by more than the return type

Comment: needed const, thanks folks!

Comment: fwiw, maybe the error message "[...] cannot be overloaded" confused you. The full message is " ... cannot be overloaded with ...." (because they have same signature, apart from return type)